# How to get logged in user data into Laravel controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-authentication

I am working on laravel 5.4, i have used the auth for user login at client side,now i want the logged in user details at the Controller,

view side by writing below code i got that:

```
{{ Auth::user()->name }} // this works on view page only.
```

Suggest me the library files with the code.
I want to display some user data like name,age,dob,etc after logged in.

Comment: Jeez, did you at least check the documentation before asking that question?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The laravel `Auth` Facade is used to get the autheticated user data as

```
$user = Auth::user();
print_r($user);
```

This will work in your controller and view both, but you have to include it as

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
```

Answer (score 7):

Just use the helper function you won't need to instantiate or import any class.

```
$user = auth()->user();
```

then `dd($user);`
you'll have a full data on user.

you can then pull what you want.

```
$user->name
```

etc...

Answer (score 3):

This should work

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

// Get the currently authenticated user...
$user = Auth::user();
```

But you have to use `use`

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Laravel has helpler for that.
u can use auth() anywhere.
for example:

```
auth()->user()->name
```

or check if not authentificated:

```
if(! auth()->user()){}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can access the user in any controller using

```
$user = Auth::user();
```

You should then be able to get details of the user by doing things like

```
$user_id = $user->id; //or Auth::user()->id;
$user_email = $user->email; // or Auth::user()->email;
```

See more details here https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication#retrieving-the-authenticated-user

Answer (score 2):

You can use `auth()->user->name`

Answer (score 2):

Use the facade

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
```

And

```
$user = Auth::user();
```

NOTE: You can call specific column in this library like `$user = Auth::user()->name;` or `->address` etc.

Answer (score 0):

`$user = Auth::user();`

You could get the current user into the user variable.

Answer (score 0):

For authentication purpose we can use middleware in controller given as below

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
    
}
```

Then write in your function `$user = Auth::user();`

Answer (score 0):

This worked, but on **blade.php :**

```
@auth
    <form action="/registration" method="post" enctype=multipart/form-data>
        @csrf
      <div class="form-floating">
        <input id="email" name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email" value="{{ auth()->user()->email }}" readonly>
      </div>
    </form>
@endauth
```